# How to convert given datetime "2013-04-09T14:30:00Z" of "Europe/Berlin" timezone to "US/Eastern" timezone datetime

Tags: php

I have `$given_date='2013-04-09T14:30:00Z'`;

This datetime is from **Europe/Berlin** timezone and I want to convert this datetime to **US/Eastern** timezone datetime.

Comment: Note: The given date says it is from the GMT/UTC timezone (that's what the 'Z' means)

Answer (score 2):

Add below line to change the default time zone

```
date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using   php [datetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) and [datetimezone](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

```
 $given_date='2013-04-09T14:30:00Z';
 $tz     = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
 $newTz  = new DateTimeZone('US/Eastern');

 $date = new DateTime($given_date, $tz);
 $date->setTimezone($newTz);
 echo $date->format('Your required Format');
```